# Abréviations de «société à responsabilité limitée»

Tags: abréviations, droit-et-justice

Dans mon travail au Canada, j’ai vu une belle variation dans l’abréviation de «société à responsabilité limitée».  Quelles versions sont les meilleures, lesquelles, acceptables, et lesquelles, des inventions de locuteurs anglophones (comme moi)?

1. S.àr.l.
2. S.AR.L.
3. S.ÀR.L.
4. Sàrl
5. S.A.R.L.
6. Sarl
7. SARL
8. S.àR.L.
9. (autres?)

Comment: Je dirais que seule les formes 5 (S.A.R.L.) et 7 (SARL) sont correctes.

Comment: Au Luxembourg on voit fréquemment l'abréviation s.à r.l. (note: pas de point après le "à")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En règle générale, pour un [sigle](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigle), on utilise les premières lettres de chaque mot hors articles, en majuscules, en omettant en général les accents. La liste des lettres est quelquefois ajustée pour rendre le sigle prononçable. On peut mettre des points après chaque lettre, mais il est plus courant de les omettre. Si le sigle est prononcé comme un mot (acronyme), on ne met jamais de points.

> [SNCF](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNCF) (**S**ociété **n**ationale des **c**hemins de **f**er français) — on pourrait écrire S.N.C.F mais c'est rare et la SNCF elle-même ne le fait pas.
>
> [EPIC](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tablissement_public_%C3%A0_caract%C3%A8re_industriel_et_commercial) ou quelquefois ÉPIC (**é**tablissement **p**ublic à caractère **i**ndustriel et **c**ommercial) — jamais de points puisqu'on prononce « épique ». On omet le `C` de *caractère*, en partie . La prononciation fait qu'on conserve parfois l'accent.
>
> Il y a en France de nombreuses **é**coles **n**ationales, **s**upérieures et autres. La plupart donnent lieu à des sigles sans accent : [ENS](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_sup%C3%A9rieure) (**É**cole **n**ormale **s**upérieure), [ESPCI](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_sup%C3%A9rieure_de_physique_et_de_chimie_industrielles_de_la_ville_de_Paris) (**É**cole **s**upérieure de **p**hysique et de **c**himie **i**ndustrielles de la ville de Paris), [EPITA](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_pour_l%27informatique_et_les_techniques_avanc%C3%A9es) (**É**cole **p**our l'**i**nformatique et les **t**echniques **a**vancées) (écrite en générale sans accent bien qu'il s'agisse d'un acronyome prononcé « épita »), etc.

Pour une **s**ociété **à** **r**esponsabilité **l**imitée, on pourrait donc écrire SARL ou S.A.R.L. (ou SRL ou S.R.L., mais ce n'est pas l'abréviation qui a été retenue). SARL est plus courant, mais bien que le A puisse sembler euphonique, on prononce le sigle en toutes lettres (« esse à erre elle »), donc S.A.R.L. est aussi possible. En [France](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22S%C3%80RL%22+site%3Afr), la forme avec accent SÀRL est rare pour ne pas dire inexistante. Elle est en revanche relativement courant en [Suisse](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22S%C3%80RL%22+site%3Ach), plus que [SARL](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22SARL%22+site%3Ach) semblerait-il au vu du nombre d'occurrences trouvé par Google, où l'on écrit même Sàrl (je ne sais pas si l'on prononce « sarle »).

Au Canada, la notion correspondante est la [société en nom collectif à responsabilité limitée](http://www2.gouv.qc.ca/entreprises/portail/quebec/transformer?lang=fr&g=transformer&sg=&t=o&e=654423101:1450431854), abrégée SENCRL. Pas de question d'accentuation à se poser donc.

Vu du Canada, tu peux utiliser SARL pour une société française et SÀRL pour une société suisse...

Comment: J’ai toujours mis un point d’honneur à écrire ÉNS. Je tente de prononcer l’accent, mais j’avoue que c’est plus difficile.

Comment: @Édouard Écrire ÉNS serait une faute. Ou alors une volonté de se démarquer du lot (ce qui certes ne dépare pas de l'endroit).

Comment: Pourquoi en serait-ce une ? Dans le fond, ce n’est pas l’ecole normale supérieure.

Comment: @Édouard La langue n'est pas toujours logique. La tradition veut que l'on écrive ENS. De plus on prononce [ə.ɛn.ɛs] et pas [e.ɛn.ɛs].

Comment: Si c’est une affaire de tradition, peut-on vraiment me reprocher une faute ? Je vois transparaître (peut-être à tort) dans ENS la détestable habitude d’omettre les accents sur les capitales. Celle qui fait que, d’après l’État, je m’appeler /əduaʁ/ et non /eduaʁ/.

Comment: @Édouard Le nom complet est « École normale supérieure » (avec un accent sur le E puisque c'est ainsi que s'écrit le mot *école*, et un É majuscule puisqu'il s'agit d'un nom propre) mais le sigle est ENS.

Answer (score 3):

Le [Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique](http://granddictionnaire.com) (GDT) indique que l’abréviation est tout en majuscule et sans accent, mais la cite avec ou sans point (SARL ou S.A.R.L.) selon la notice en question. Le Petit Robert ne la donne qu'avec des points.

Toutefois, le *Français au Bureau*, une autre publication de l'Office de la langue française, cite les abréviations de *société en commandite* et *société en nom collectif* sans points.

Je crois donc que si S.A.R.L. et SARL sont toutes les deux valides, SARL est peut-être plus recommandable si on tient à choisir une option selon des critères de « correction », surtout si elle est fréquemment prononcée comme un acronyme (mais je ne sais pas si c'est le cas).

Comment: Heu comment on fait pour prononcer ça comme un acronyme ? Ça fait pas très français quand même.

Comment: Je ne vois pas où est le problème... ce n'est jamais qu'un /s/ ajouté à *Arles*....

Answer (score 1):

En complément à la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7726/1129) de Circeus, [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SARL) indique que les sigles utilisés sont

> [...] SARL, S.A.R.L., parfois SÀRL ou SàRl

Answer (score 1):

Comme expert-comptable et commissaire aux comptes, je peux affirmer que seuls SARL, ou bien S.A.R.L. sont admissibles. Jamais vu les autres (ou alors, en toutes lettres), et la mention sur tout papier à en-tête, avec entre autres le montant du capital, est obligatoire.

Cela n'est valable qu'en France métropolitaine ou d'outre-mer, j'ignore pour les autres pays francophones.